# Stop recursion in postgres as soon as the condition is met

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have this table of a hierarchy

```
select * from product_categories;
 id | parent_id |     item     |     rule
----+-----------+--------------+---------------
  1 |           | ecomm        |
  2 |         1 | grocceries   |
  3 |         1 | electronics  |
  5 |         3 | TV           |
  6 |         4 | touch_screen | Rules applied
  7 |         4 | qwerty       |
  8 |         6 | iphone       |
  4 |         3 | mobile       | mobile rules
```

I want to traverse from iphone and as soon as I encounter row with 'rule' not NULL, I want to select that row and finish recursion then and there only,
I am using this query,

```
WITH RECURSIVE items AS (
        SELECT id, item, parent_id, rule
        FROM product_categories
        WHERE item = 'iphone'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT p.id, p.item, p.parent_id, p.rule
        FROM product_categories p
        JOIN items ON p.id = items.parent_id
        WHERE p.rule is not NULL
)
SELECT * FROM items ;
```

giving the result,

```
 id |     item     | parent_id |     rule
----+--------------+-----------+---------------
  8 | iphone       |         6 |
  6 | touch_screen |         4 | Rules applied
  4 | mobile       |         3 | mobile rules
```

What I want here is as soon as the row with rule column not NULL found, it should return that row and finish the recursion,
In above example it should return the second row with item 'touch_screen',
But it is printing the 3rd row also.

How can I modify this query to achieve this goal

Comment: What do you mean by "select that row"? The recursion will select all rows until you stop the recursion by some predicate. Do you want to exclude the previous nodes from the graph navigation?

Comment: Finding a condition to stop recursion as soon as the desired result is reached is a good practice. Limiting recursion is always better than filtering its results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to stop recursion when the current node's `rule` is not null and its child's `rule` is null:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE items AS (
        SELECT id, item, parent_id, rule
        FROM product_categories
        WHERE item = 'iphone'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT p.id, p.item, p.parent_id, p.rule
        FROM product_categories p
        JOIN items ON p.id = items.parent_id
        WHERE items.rule IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM items;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/HOx2xT5C)

Comment: there's a bug in this query, when I set row with item 'touch_screen'  as NULL, it should run till the item 'mobile' where rule is not NULL, 
but it is only printing the row with item 'iphone'

Comment: Yes, I left the original condition unnecessarily, sorry. The answer updated.

Comment: working now, thanks